# How to add an item to my "Send To" context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

On my old XP machine I would simply copy shortcuts into the `%userprofile%\SendTo` folder. On Windows-7 this folder is hidden, and I don't have access to it (which surprised me, it is *my* SendTo folder after all).

Is there an "approved" way of adding to my Send To menu that I'm unaware of? 
Or do I need extra permissions from our system administrators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apologies,
    A little extra googling found it on [How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/)

The folder is now at `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`

Thanks,
BW

Comment: Actually, the folder is represented by `FOLDERID_SendTo`. You should never rely in hard-coding default paths.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: I did a quick google for that but I don't understand it's context' Should I be able to run `dir %FOLDERID_SendTo%` from a command prompt? Thanks.

Comment: From a batch file you have no choice. When fiddling with this yourself on your machine do whatever works. However, if you put things there with a program you should use the proper APIs to get the folder since `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` is merely the *default* path. There is no guarantee that the actual folder really resides there.

Comment: Since it is a shell folder, the chances approach 100% that it is located at the default location. However, it may be hard-linked from another location as well. Ordinarily, simply typing the path to a folder in the Run box will open it, but you will get an error without the "shell:" command if target is a symbolic link of some kind.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative, easier to remember, quicker and fail safe way to get the the Send To folder is to type `shell:sendto` in the Start Menu search box.  The location contains ordinary application shortcuts.

**UPDATE:**
For Windows 10 (and probably 8) this doesn't work with the Start Menu, so you have to use Win+R and use the Run box instead.

Comment: +1 Excellent! Have you a reference to other `shell:` commands? Can they be used in places other than the _Run_ dialog e.g. Can they be used in batch commands, Powershell scripts etc? Thanks

Comment: @Binary: Sure.  As you can see, there are loads of them, but they cannot be used in scripts, as far as I know :  http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/