# How to add an item to my “Send To” context menu in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I want to add an application shortcut to my Send To context menu in Windows 8; I tried the solution for Windows 7 here: [How to add an item to my "Send To" context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/139968/how-to-add-an-item-to-my-send-to-context-menu) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Add your shortcut there.

Note: it might be more correct to run: `shell: sendto`

Comment: You welcome, I will improve the answer a bit.

Comment: `shell: sendto` is a more accurate method.